# Can I use rollup to bundle dependencies in their separate files?

Tags: javascript, bundle, rollup

Let's say I am building a webapp that depends on react, a bunch of small util libraries and then has my own code.

When bundling the code, I would like to put it into 3 bundles

1. react, react-dom and others like react-router-dom
2. Small util libraries
3. My own code

While I can use rollup to bundle my code into one file and include dependencies or not, is it possible to create the files for 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that as rollup has parameters to choose the config you can create 3 different configs one for each bundle or you can configure it to create all 3 in a single step but I would go for 3 independent bundles

```
rollup -c deps-react.js && rollup -c deps-small-util.js && rollup -c
```